NextJs route interception with mantine/core Modal
I'm working on a nextjs app where I do some route interception to show modals, like in the documentation. I've been able to successfully set it up using the NextUI Modal component but I need to set one up using the Mantine/core modal. I can't figure out the correct way to handle the opened state to get the modal to behave correctly.
The code is structured as follows:
app/
  trips/
    page.tsx
    layout.tsx
    default.tsx
    create/
      page.tsx
    @modal/
      default.tsx
      (.)create/
        page.tsx
        CreateTripModal.tsx

In trips:
    // page.tsx

    export default function Page() {
        const router = useRouter()
        const handleCreateTripClicked = () => {
            return router.push(`/trips/create`)
        }
        return (
            <>
                <Button onClick={handleCreateTripClicked}>
                    New Trip
                </Button>
            </>
        );
      }
    
    // layout.tsx
    export default function Layout(props: {
        children: React.ReactNode;
        modal: React.ReactNode;
    }) {
        return (<>
            {props.children}
            {props.modal}
        </>);
    }
    
    // default.tsx
    export default function Default() {
        return null;
    }


@modal/default.tsx
export default function Default() {
    return null;
}

@modal/(.)create
page.tsx

    import CreateTripModal from './CreateTripModal';

    
    export default function Modal() {
        return <CreateTripModal></CreateTripModal>;
    }

CreateTripModal.tsx
    export default function CreateTripModal() {
        const [opened, { open, close }] = useDisclosure(true);
        const router = useRouter();
        const handleModalClosed = () => {
            close();
            return router.push(`/trips`)
        }
        return (
            <Modal
                title='Create Trip'
                opened={opened}
                onClose={handleModalClosed}
                size='lg'>
            { ... }
            </Modal>

With this code in CreateTripModal.tsx, the route redirects to the correct path and the modal appears, but if you close it and try to re-open it, it will redirect to the path but the modal will not appear:
    import { useDisclosure } from '@mantine/hooks';
    import { Modal } from '@mantine/core';
    import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
    
    export default function CreateTripModal() {
        const [opened, { open, close }] = useDisclosure(true);
        const router = useRouter();
        const handleModalClosed = () => {
            close();
            return router.push(`/trips`)
        }
        return (
            <Modal
                title='Create Trip'
                opened={opened}
                onClose={handleModalClosed}
                size='lg'
            >
            { ... }
           </Modal>

I tried adding useEffect() to manually call open() on render, but the behavior remains the same as above:
    useEffect(() => {
       open();
    }, [])

To my understanding, the modal should be unmounted on close by default but I tried both the keepMounted={false} and keepMounted={true} prop and still no success. Throwing a console.log in the render function seems to indicate that it's not being rendered the second time the button on trips/page is clicked to redirect to trips/create.
Any ideas?
